# How to set RViz (in PC without ROS) to access remote PC (with ROS)

Tags: rviz, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on a project that has a Robot with Raspberry Pi controlling it and the data of the Robot's diagnostics is sent by Raspberry Pi to a Desktop PC over Wifi. I am able to establish the communication between Desktop PC and Raspberry Pi over Network by referring this: [Running ROS across multiple machines](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines)
I am already done with the results if both the Raspberry Pi and Desktop PC are having ROS installed.
I have a launch file called "view_robot.launch" that invokes the RViz and sets the Robot Parametric Environment. Here is the content of the file:

```
    <launch>
<arg name="model" />
<!-- Parsing xacro and setting robot_description parameter -->
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(find mobile_robot_description)/urdf/robot_model.xacro" />
<!-- Starting robot state publish which will publish tf -->
<node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher" />
<!-- Launch visualization in rviz -->
<node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find mobile_robot_description)/config/robot.rviz" required="true" /> </launch>
```

Now I need to remove ROS from Desktop PC, Open RViz in it and connect to my Raspberry Pi's roslaunch server that is not having a unique address. Is it possible? If Yes, then I need some references with which I can implement this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304443/how-to-set-rviz-(in-pc-without-ros)-to-access-remote-pc-(with-ros)/) by [Shaunak Vyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/37404/shaunak-vyas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2018-09-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

RVIZ is part of ROS if you uninstall ROS you can' run RVIZ? It's not a stand alone application but a fully integrated part of ROS that can't work on it's own.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Shaunak Vyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/37404/shaunak-vyas/) on 2018-10-08**:
@PeteBlackerThe3rd

```
RVIZ is part of ROS if you uninstall ROS you can't run RVIZ. It's not a stand alone application but a fully integrated part of ROS that can't work on it's own.
```

Thank you for clearing the confusion.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-10-11**:
No problem.